# How to subtract a day from an invalid date in shell script?

Tags: shell, date, sh

I'm working on a script to automate the download of information from a customer in the period from 00:00 to 23:59 on the same day. To make the correct treatment of the first day of daylight saving time (10/15/2017, in my timezone - BRST), I need to check the timezone of the previous day. However, when I will subtract one day from the first valid time,

```
date --date="20171015 01:00 -1 day" +%Y-%m-%d
```

the result is the next day `2017-10-16`, not the previous day `2017-10-14`. Could anyone help me understand what I might be doing wrong and how should I do this operation in the right way?

Comment: do you know about the `TZ=` env var? Check you `man date` for how your system is using it (it may, or may not help for your case). Good luck.

Comment: Date arithmetic gets flaky. I tried `... 01:00 -1 hour` with various days, and consistently got 23:00 on the previous day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really trust GNU `date`'s arithmetic. Instead, I would convert your starting time to seconds since the UNIX epoch, subtract 86400 seconds, and convert the result back to a day. Those conversion routines take daylight saving time into account.

```
$ TZ=BRST date +%s --date "20171015 01:00"
1508029200
$ TZ=BRST date +%F-%T --date @$((1508029200 - 86400))
2017-10-14-01:00:00
```

Comment: Hi, @chepner! This approach worked for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It appears the "BRST" timezone is not very useful: stick to Olson timezone names

```
$ TZ=BRST date --date="20171015 00:30" "+%F %T"
2017-10-15 00:30:00

$ TZ=America/Sao_Paulo date --date="20171015 00:30" "+%F %T"
date: invalid date ‘20171015 00:30’
```